# how to know if curl script worked

Tags: xml, apache, shell, curl

So I'm trying to use cURL to download a xml file that is hosted on the web (https://), and that, every five minutes. Therefore, I've created a crontab to activate a script periodically:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/curl /var/www/html/script.sh
```

My script.sh looks like this (it's in the same directory as the StationSchedule.xml file):

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -o "StationSchedule.xml" "<URL_OF_THE_WEBSITE>"
```

I use the headers I found using the crome developper tools.

However, the xml file doesn't seem to be updated as it should be, what is my problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your crontab is incorrect because you are trying to run curl with a shell script as its first argument and this will never work.

1. Remove /usr/bin/curl from your crontab
2. Set execute permissions on /var/www/html/script.sh as `chmod +x /var/www/html/script.sh`
3. Provide the complete path to your StationSchedule.xml file. For e.g `curl -o "/tmp/StationSchedule.xml"`

Comment: I've tried the three steps, but the file is still not updated.

Comment: How could I know that? (sorry, it's my first time doing that)

Comment: On your terminal, simply run /var/www/html/script.sh

Comment: -bash: /var/www/html/script.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: I'm using putty to ssh to my server

Comment: Can you please paste the output of these two commands? `cat -evt /var/www/html/script.sh` and `ls -l /bin/bash` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63446/discussion-between-linuxfan-and-jonathan).

Comment: The script had a CTRL-M character and hence it wouldn't execute. After removing those characters using strings, it works as expected.